# Continuos datasource crash

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly

I'm developing a web application using JavaServer Faces for presentation, Wildly 17 as container and MySQL 8 as database.

I have deployed the MySQL connector 8.0.15 (the .jar file) and set the parameters for the datasource, as described in the Wildfly's user guide.
In Details:

- com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver for the Driver Class
- min pool size: 10
- max pool size: 20
- pool refill: true

Now, the problem is: the execution of the most simple query is very slow (as simple query I mean something like (`select field from table`, where the table has 20 rows).

In all the use case, after a certain small number of interaction the datasource became null and the only way to solve the problem is to reboot the container.

A query that I want to execute multiple times in a while cycle (because I need to increment a timestamp and re-execute the query) crash as soon as more than 144 lines are involved (in a join of 3 table).

In this case, after 10 minute of execution, I receive this message:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447:
Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80107:1a1a9a9e:5d85e7db:17 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >,
owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
```

Here is some lines of the stack trace (it's too long that the console can't maintain all lines).

The longest table involved has 200 000 rows.

Here is the EJB declaration

```
@Remote
public interface DatabaseDriver{

...

}

@Stateful
public class DatabaseDriverImpl implements DatabaseDriver {

...

    @Resource(lookup = "java:/MySqlDS")
    DataSource ds;

...

}
```

And here is the method that crash

```
public List<AggregateResult> getAggregatePrecipitation(String stationSn, Timestamp startDate, Timestamp stopDate, long scaleFactor){

    if(GlobalVariables.debug) {
        System.out.println(TAG + " enter getAggregatePrecipitation");
    }

    //Converto lo scaleFactor da ore a millisecondi
    scaleFactor = scaleFactor * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    //Converto i timestamp passati in millisecondi
    long startMillis = startDate.getTime();
    long stopMillis = stopDate.getTime();

    //Variablie incrementale
    long currStopMillis = startMillis + scaleFactor;

    //Risultato
    float currRes = 0;
    AggregateResult apr = null;
    List<AggregateResult> res = new ArrayList<AggregateResult>();

    Connection connection = null;

    try {

        connection = ds.getConnection();

        if(testConnection(connection)) {

            if(GlobalVariables.verbose) {
                System.out.println(TAG + " execute query");
            }

            while(currStopMillis < stopMillis) {

                startDate = new Timestamp(startMillis);
                stopDate = new Timestamp(currStopMillis);

                CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call " + "GET_AGGREGATE_PRECIPITATION(?, ?, ?, ?)}"); 
                cs.setString(1, stationSn);
                cs.setTimestamp(2, startDate);
                cs.setTimestamp(3, stopDate);
                cs.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);
                cs.execute();

                currRes = cs.getFloat(4);
                apr = new AggregateResult(stopDate, currRes);
                res.add(apr);

                startMillis = currStopMillis;
                currStopMillis += scaleFactor;
            }

            if(GlobalVariables.verbose) {
                System.out.println(TAG + " query executed. Result: ");

                for(AggregateResult a : res) {
                    System.out.println(a);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //TODO: Gestire l'eccezione
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        connection = null;
    }

    if(GlobalVariables.debug) {
        System.out.println(TAG + " exit getAggregatePrecipitation");
    }

    return res;
}
```

and the stored procedure in the database

```
BEGIN
    set aggregatePrecipitation = (
        select sum(RG.value)
        from datum D, rain_gauge_datum RG, production P 
        where D.id = RG.id and P.ref_datum = D.id and D.data_type = 'RG'
        and P.ref_station = stationSn 
        and D.creation_date >= startDate and D.creation_date <= stopDate
    );
END
```

Log with exception:

```
11:11:36,220 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0487: Unexpected invocation state 0
11:11:36,220 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default task-1) ARJUNA012077: Abort called on already aborted atomic action 0:ffffc0a80107:1a1a9a9e:5d85e7db:17
11:11:36,221 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component DatabaseDriverImpl for method public abstract java.util.List it.idrologiaUnipa.dao.DatabaseDriver.getAllData(java.lang.String,java.sql.Timestamp,java.sql.Timestamp): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80107:1a1a9a9e:5d85e7db:17 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back

...

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80107:1a1a9a9e:5d85e7db:17 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95)
    ... 119 more

...

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFLYEJB0447: Transaction 'Local transaction (delegate=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80107:1a1a9a9e:5d85e7db:17 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED >, owner=Local transaction context for provider JBoss JTA transaction provider)' was already rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@17.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95)
    ... 119 more
```

Then the datasource variable became null.

```
11:51:18,749 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/MySqlDS

...
11:51:18,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/MySqlDS
11:51:18,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
11:51:18,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
11:51:18,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
11:51:18,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
11:51:18,766 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 132 more
11:51:18,767 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000655: No managed connections available within configured blocking timeout (30000 [ms])
11:51:18,767 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:570)
11:51:18,767 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:714)
11:51:18,767 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:613)
11:51:18,767 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.16.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
11:51:18,767 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    ... 135 more
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just trying to run code for longer than the transaction limit? I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with this method, but from a very quick scan looks like it could spend a while running over and over in the while section

Comment: You also never actually close the connection to the database, in your finally block you need to close, not just set your variable to null

Comment: @WillT Thanks for your answer. I'm using a while cycle to shift the 2 timestamps (named startDate and stopDate in the code above) because I need to iterate the same query over several time windows. I don't know if I can do that in SQL and I know that this code isn't the best for performance. But, the problem cannot be caused by the incorrect closure of the connection (after I read your comment I immediately adjust this), because the other face of the problem is the very very slow execution of all query, not only of this strange code.